# id field inside object, NEST for elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

So, I have an object with an `Id` field; when I index it, the resulting document has the `_source.id` field as expected, but the `_id` field has the same value as `_source.id`.

For instance, I have this object:

```
var obj = new Obj {
    ...
    Id = 'some_value',
    ...
};
```

After indexing, I see that the ES document is like so:

```
{
    ...
    "_id: "some_value",
    ...
    "_source" : {
        ...
        "id" : "some_value",
        ...
    }
}
```

The question is: is it possible to somehow disable this behavior? like, how can I let Elasticsearch generate the value for `_id` (if possible)?

Comment: How are you indexing your data?

Comment: mostly defaults, letting the client infer the mappings and such: `client.IndexDocumentAsync(obj)`

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the library you're using. Which is it?

Comment: I used NEST 6.0.2

Answer (score 3):

This is a feature known as [Id inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-inference.html). If you would prefer NEST not do it, I would recommend either

- Renaming your `Id` property on the POCO to something else
- Attribute the POCO with `ElasticsearchType` and assign a non-existent property name to `IdProperty`

```cs
[ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "do_not_infer_id")]
public class MyDocument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```